# node.js library for extracting words from a text

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, unicode

I'm looking for feedback on my library for extracting words from a text: https://npmjs.org/package/uwords

The extracted word is defined as sequence of Unicode characters from Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo groups. So the code of the main part is (https://github.com/AlexAtNet/uwords/blob/master/index.js#L9):

```
module.exports = function (text) {
    var words, word, index, limit, code;

    words = [ ];
    word = null;

    for (index = 0, limit = text.length; index < limit; index += 1) {
        code = text.charCodeAt(index);
        if (-1 === _.indexOf(letters, code, true)) {
            if (null !== word) {
                words.push(word.join(''));
                word = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (null === word) {
                word = [ ];
            }
            word.push(String.fromCharCode(code));
        }
    }

    if (null !== word) {
        words.push(word.join(''));
    }

    return words;
};
```

and the array `letters` was created as follows (https://github.com/AlexAtNet/uwords/blob/master/gruntfile.js#L59):

```
    grunt.registerTask('create-letters-json', 'letters.json', function () {
        var letters, compacted;

        letters = [
            require('unicode/category/Lu'),
            require('unicode/category/Ll'),
            require('unicode/category/Lt'),
            require('unicode/category/Lm'),
            require('unicode/category/Lo')
        ].reduce(function (list, item) {
            list.push.apply(list, Object.keys(item).map(function (value) {
                return parseInt(value, 10);
            }));
            return list;
        }, [ ]).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });

        compacted = (function (list) {
            var result, item, idx, value;

            result = [ ];

            item = { begin : list[0], end : list[0] };
            result.push(item);

            for (idx = 1; idx < list.length; idx += 1) {
                value = list[idx];
                if (item.end + 1 === value) {
                    item.end = value;
                } else {
                    item = { begin : list[idx], end : list[idx] };
                    result.push(item);
                }
            }

            for (idx = 0; idx < result.length; idx += 1) {
                item = result[idx];
                if (item.begin === item.end) {
                    result[idx] = item.begin;
                } else {
                    result[idx] = [ item.begin, item.end ];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }(letters));

        require('fs').writeFileSync(__dirname + '/letters.json',
            JSON.stringify(compacted, null, 2));
    });
```

It is quite naive approach but I think that it will work in most of the cases. What do you think?

Comment: I have not used node js. However, I wonder if you could simply use string replace?

Comment: Sorry, did not get it - what do you mean by "use string replace"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top part looks clean, personally I would

- Not compare with `null` all the time, just check `word.length` and have `word` be an array at all times.
- Not initialize `word` and `words` separately
- Not use `String.fromCharCode(code)`, I would use `text[index]` instead
- I would use the `~` operator instead of comparing to `-1`
- I would first deal with finding a match , and then with not finding a match ( switch the `if` blocks in other words ), my mind had to do a double take when I was reading your code
- if would add a space to the end of `text`, so that I would not need the last if statement

All that would give me something like:

```
module.exports = function (text){
 text += " ";  

 var words = [], 
     word  = [], 
     limit = text.length, code, index;

    for (index = 0; index < limit; index += 1) {
        code = text.charCodeAt(index);
        if (~_.indexOf(letters, code, true)) {
          word.push( text[index] )
        } else {
          if (word.length) {
            words.push(word.join(''));
            word = [];
          }
        }
    }
    return words;
};
```

Finally, I think collecting char-codes in the 2nd script, then taking chars, converting those to char-codes and then use the chars again might not be the best approach.

Personally, I would `letters` be an object where each letter ( not the char-code ) would be a property of the object set to true. No more char-code conversions, and most likely it would beat the sorted lookup table. ( To be tested.. )

Comment: I've tried to use properties instead of the binary search, and it is much faster - but it is not consistent. For some reason `console.log(String.fromCharCode(195101) === String.fromCharCode(64029))` and as the result the `letters.length - Object.keys(obj).length = 1583` `obj = letters.reduce(function (tmp, item) { tmp[String.fromCharCode(item)] = item; return tmp; }, { }))`

Comment: Happy that it is faster, disconcerting that you found that behaviour, I am fairly certain that you will win a ton of rep if you ask about this on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used node js. However, I wonder if you could simply use string replace? For example,

```
v = 'I was walking down the park on day. I was running down the block'
j = message.replace(/was/g, '')
```

The output would be the following.

```
'I  walking down the park one day. I  here'
```

Comment: Hi James, please post comments *as comments*. I flagged this post as "not an answer".